# Why can't you upvote a comment after you've undone your upvote?

Tags: discussion, comments, up-votes

I accidentally upvoted a comment, and I un-upvoted it (are there better words for vocabulary like this?). Blender StackExchange gave me an alert via my web browser that I wouldn't be able to re-upvote it after I un-upvoted it. I was wondering why this restriction exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/238438):

> We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past. The only use case is undoing a mis-click.